# Google Cloud Endpoints workflow

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

Why is it that the Cloud Endpoints workflow involves writing the backend first and then generating the client libraries as opposed to writing the CRUD for the client layer first and then generating the cloud stubs for the CRUD operations on the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem than you when I started Google Cloud Endpoints with Android.

**First**, you have to write CRUD classes and endpoints methods on your App Engine Backend. 
This amazing website explain you how to do that : http://rominirani.com/2014/01/13/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-2/

**Then**, you can generate the client librairies for your android app: http://rominirani.com/2014/01/16/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-3/

Hope that will help you !